# Using rangefind

Tags: vba, excel

I have three sheets, sheet S, Sheet P and Sheet Data.

I first copy the column of Sheet S to Sheet Data. Then in column E of sheet Data, I look for the ID. The ID In column E of data sheet, matches with the column A of P sheet, then I copy the corresponding ID.

The problem here is the Sheet data  contains 214 rows, while sheet P contains 1110. 
while comparing the ID, there are two different ID from row 870 and 871, which are not copied, even though they are same.

Could someone guide what could be the reason ?

```
Sub lookup()
Dim lLastrow, totalrows As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from S to Data
With Sheets("S")
  lLastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  .Range("P5:P" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("E5")
  .Range("G5:G" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("H5")
End With

totalrows = Sheets("P").Cells(Sheets("P").Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lLastrow
  'Search for the value on P_APQP
  With Sheets("P")
    Set rng = .Columns(1).Find(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value & "*", lookat:=xlWhole)
  End With

  'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Data")
      .Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
      .Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
      .Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
      .Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
      .Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
      .Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
      .Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
      .Cells(i, 14).Value = rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
      .Cells(i, 15).Value = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
      .Cells(i, 16).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
    End With
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Be aware that `Dim lLastrow, totalrows As Long` only declares the last variable as `Long` the first one is automatically `Variant`. This is exactly the same as `Dim lLastrow As Variant, totalrows As Long`. If you want both variables to be of type `Long` then you need to specify a type for **every** variable like `Dim lLastrow As Long, totalrows As Long`.

Comment: You need to loop and use FindNext if your values occur more than once. There are plenty of examples online - give it a whirl and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: @SJR my value occurs only once.

Comment: So what did your comment "two ID from row 870 and 871" mean?

Comment: @SJR  I mean they are two different ID  from row 870 and 871. eg: D2E15706000 & D2E16047901

Comment: @SJR Sorry for the confusion with my commet

Comment: Your code goes through column E of "Data" sheet, searches for each value in column A of "P" sheet. If the value is found, it copies values from P to Data. Correct? Where are the ID values located?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154231/discussion-between-mikz-and-sjr).

Comment: @SJR I have mentioned in chat

Comment: @SJR 
Yeah you are correct. Column E of data sheet and column A of P sheet both contains the ID


If these two ID matches then it copies the ID from P to Data

Comment: @SJR trim function did not help me. Is there any other method to do the same ?

Comment: When I try `Set rng = .Columns(1).Find(Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value) & "*", lookat:=xlWhole)` it works. Is that what you tried?

Comment: Yeah its the same I tried

Comment: @SJR can you post your code as answer. It worked :) I was looking at xlpart instead of xlwhole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the whole code. I also made an adjustment to your first line of declarations - as you had it, only totalrows was being declared as Long. You have to spell each one out I'm afraid.

```
Sub lookup()

Dim lLastrow As Long, totalrows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("S")
    lLastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("P5:P" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("E5")
    .Range("G5:G" & lLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("H5")
End With

totalrows = Sheets("P").Cells(Sheets("P").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lLastrow
  'Search for the value on P_APQP
    With Sheets("P")
        'amended below
        Set rng = .Columns(1).Find(Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value) & "*", lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With

    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Data")
            .Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
            .Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
            .Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
            .Cells(i, 14).Value = rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
            .Cells(i, 15).Value = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Cells(i, 16).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```